# JSON.deserialise a date

Tags: apex, json

Ok, so I can get a String like:

```
13-06-29
```

and do:

```
JSON.deserialize('"13-06-29"')
```

and it's fine. I get a Date object for the 29th June 2013.  However, how does deserialize now I am using `YY-MM-DD` and how can I be sure that this format will always be used?

Can I explicitly specify a `YY-MM-DD` format?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The format you are trying to force is [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

You could use [JSON parser](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_jsonparser.htm) `getDateValue` which will parse a ISO 8601 date value. Finally remember to catch the exception if the value is not a valid date.

```
String JSONContent =
   '{"dateOfBirth":"2011-03-22"}';
JSONParser parser = 
   JSON.createParser(JSONContent);
// Advance to the start object marker.
parser.nextToken();
// Advance to the next value.
parser.nextValue();
// Get the date of birth.
Date dob = parser.getDateValue();
```

Comment: thanks but I want to know how the JSON parser or deserialiser knows my date is ISO 8601?

Comment: JavaScript specifies that valid date formats will be ISO 8601 formatted. JSON makes no such assertion, but any EMCAScript 5.1 compliant code should format dates in this pattern. Apparently some vendors had other ideas, but the standards have converged, so this should probably be a safe bet.